# iPhone, Swift, UIWebView. The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Я новичок в iOS разработке, возможно задаю глупый вопрос, но я не нашел в инете ответа на него (точнее те отыеты которые я находил, мне не помогли)...

Есть приложение, он открывает сайт используя UIWebView, пробовал WKWebKit - он вообще сайт не грузит и в логах ни чего не говорит... а вот с UIWebView ругается на сертификат:

```
2019-02-14 18:22:04.628431+0500 treacingOil[2262:111637] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x2804a76c0]: 3:0
2019-02-14 18:22:04.662934+0500 treacingOil[2262:111637] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)
2019-02-14 18:22:04.663003+0500 treacingOil[2262:111637] Task <1890E393-18B0-4CC1-B7AF-F857932D5169>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9807])
2019-02-14 18:22:04.663678+0500 treacingOil[2262:111637] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “consolidate.logicon-group.ru” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

аналогичное приложение есть на андройд, но там есть возможность игнорировать эту ошибку и там все работает. А вот как в Swift это сделать для iOS... у меня не получилось... находил возможные варианты решения в инете, пробовал, не работают... все равно ругаются на сертификат... 
Еще интересно то, что это же приложение нормально работает на iPad, а в iPhone-ах не работает (буквально 2-3 месяца назад работало), версия iOS что на айфоне что на айпаде одинаковая, 12-я, хотя, может они все таки разные...
Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? 
Может как нибудь все таки можно игнорировать этот сертификат?

Добавил код приложения, хотя он очень простой, как обычный пример приложения-браузера, который просто должен открывать определенную страницу:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cStartPage = "https://mysomesite.ru/view/"
    let cMobileStartPage = "\(cStartPage)m_index.html"

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadPage(cMobileStartPage)

    }

    func loadPage(_ str: String){
        if let url = URL(string:str){
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код то покажите. Мы не ясновидящие. И скажите, вы в info.plist добавляли доступ к Интернету?

Comment: Он простой, поэтому изначально не стал добавлять, но теперь добавил. Про доступ в info.plist, если имеете в виду AppTransportSecurity и все что касается него (AllowsArbitraryLoads, AllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent, и т.д.), то да, пробовал, в различных комбинациях/вариантах, не помогло...

Comment: Я проверил, с вашим кодом все в порядке, так что возможно дело в конкретном сайте. Адрес сайта является секретным или нет?